# use attemptCount in bot Framework v4 to end the whole conversation/prompt

Tags: botframework

Is it possible to end the whole conversation/prompt once number of attempts has been done.

```
 //validate mobile
    async mobileValidator(promptContext) {
        let first3Digits = String(promptContext.recognized.value);
        console.log(promptContext.attemptCount);

        if(promptContext.attemptCount > 3) {
            return await promptContext.endDialog();
        }
        return promptContext.recognized.succeeded && first3Digits.substring(0, 3) == '639' && String(promptContext.recognized.value).length == 12;

    }
```

the code shows my validator function to check whether user inputted a valid mobile number and attemptCounts is not reached, of course it renders an error like this:

```
TypeError: promptContext.endDialog is not a function
```

but I can't also just return false value to the prompt (if max attempt is reached) cause it will infinitely ask the user (as what I understand the promptvalidator only returns true or false, if true proceed if false reprompt)

Is there a way to end the conversation using a validator?

Thanks!

PS. I used a [NumberPrompt()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-dialogs/numberprompt?view=botbuilder-ts-latest) for this one.

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done. The validator itself is expected to return true or false. But you could still potentially call end dialog from within the function. The problem is that promptContext is a TurnContext, not a DialogContext, and it seems the regular methods such as endDialog() don't work. I tried a few things such as passing dialog state and creating a new context, trying to access the parent dialog, etc. but nothing was working. I can see the dialog stack in the turn context but don't know how to modify it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Leaving custom prompt validation in Bot Framework V4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56790417/leaving-custom-prompt-validation-in-bot-framework-v4)

Comment: Hi @KyleDelaney , it is but I dont really speak C# so how do you translate this to nodeJS:
```if (promptContext.AttemptCount > 3)
{
    var dc = await BotUtil.Dialogs.CreateContextAsync(promptContext.Context, cancellationToken);
    await dc.CancelAllDialogsAsync(cancellationToken);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @KyleDelaney , I tried 1.1 and had this code but cancellAllDialogs just dont work.
```
if(promptContext.attemptCount > 3) {
            await promptContext.context.sendActivity("Too many attempt");
            return await promptContext.cancelAllDialogs();
        }
```

Comment: @AleimarVillabrille - `promptContext` has no `cancelAllDialogs` method. In my example, `BotUtil.Dialogs` is a dialog set. You need to create a dialog context from a dialog set like my example shows if you want to use that option. The v4 SDK's all work the same way, so no knowledge of C# is needed. And please refer to the documentation and the source code so that you're not trying to call methods that aren't there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-dialogs/promptvalidatorcontext

Comment: @AleimarVillabrille - Are you still working on this?

Comment: yep. still in my to do list. @KyleDelaney (kinda overloaded with other tasks)

Comment: @AleimarVillabrille - Can you tell me what information you need that's not in the answer to the other question?

Comment: @billoverton what did you do to end the conversation? Can you share your solution?

Comment: @AleimarVillabrille - The code samples you need are in the answer I linked. Ending the dialog from within the prompt validator is not recommended, but it is possible. If you're having trouble creating the dialog context, can you show what you've tried?

Comment: @AleimarVillabrille - Do you still need help? If so, please explain what information you need and what kind of answer you would accept. A lot of effort has been put into parity between each SDK language, so users are expected to be able to translate a solution written in one language to another language. The concepts are the same. If all you need to know is how to write an existing solution in your preferred language then that's not a bot question, but I'm still willing to help. Please make a good-faith attempt to do it yourself first as Stack Overflow recommends, then explain what went wrong.

Comment: hi @KyleDelaney, I'm so sorry for this delayed response. I forgot to check my stackoverflow account. But hey! I simply did this:
```
if(promptContext.attemptCount == 3) {
            promptContext.options.prompt = null;
            promptContext.options.retryPrompt = null;
        }
```
nullifying creates an illusion that the conversation ended. hehe, solved my issue.

Comment: @AleimarVillabrille - Go ahead and post that as an answer and accept it